# How to use templated methods to take a function as input which can be used with every signature

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I have a class that has the task to run functions in an async context and therefore can take a function (or method) as input.

Right now I am keeping two functions with different names to take the functions as input, because I need to differentiate between void return type and other return types. Naming both functions the same does not work for me. What I want is that both have the same name and the caller of the function should not need to think about the return type, he can get it, if he wants and if it is possible:

```
#include <functional>

template<typename Func, typename ...Args>
auto Foo(Func f, Args&&... args)
{
    decltype(f(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) ret; 
    init();
    ret = f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    clean();
    return ret;
}

template<typename Func, typename ...Args>
void FooVoid(Func f, Args&&... args)
{
    init();
    f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    clean();
}

int Bar(){return 0;}

void Empty() {}

struct A
{
    int Bar(){return 0;}
    void Empty(){}
};



int main()
{
    auto bar = Foo(Bar);
    FooVoid(Empty);

    A a;
    bar = Foo(std::bind(&A::Bar, a));
    FooVoid(std::bind(&A::Empty, a));

    return 0;
}
```

What I want is that both functions can have the same name without creating ambiguousity. Right now there is no other limitation. How could I achieve this? Any other recommendations on the code would also be helpful. I am new to this topic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since C++17 you can use *if constexpr*. In the condtion you check if function `f` has return type other than `void`, if so, call the function and return its value. Otherwise, `auto` as return type will be deduced to be `void` - no return in *false-statement*.

```
template<typename Func, typename ...Args>
auto Foo(Func f, Args&&... args)
{
    if constexpr (!std::is_same_v<void,decltype(f(std::forward<Args>(args)...))> )
    {
        init();
        auto ret =  f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        clean();
        return ret;
    }
    else {
        init();
        f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        clean();
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3PovMs1T9)

Comment: Good thing is in the near future we are going to have C++17 as a standard, I think If there is no other answer I will use this

Answer (score 1):

With RAII object, you might use same implementation:

```
template<typename Func, typename ...Args>
auto Foo(Func f, Args&&... args)
{
    struct Raii
    {
        Raii() { init(); }
        ~Raii() { clean(); }
    } raii;
    return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3422b52e3abc7e93)

Note: returning `void` is allowed in void-return-type functions. :-)

Comment: Nice solution, I also like to use RAII to do such things. In that case I think it could miss the point what really needs to happen, after the function is executed, because at the first glance I would think the execution of the function is the last thing to happen

Comment: Better naming than `Raii` might help :-) (`init`/`clean` are too generic for me to have a non-generic name, but with proper resource name, it might seems natural that return is the last statement). Alternative is to split differently `init(); Finally at_end_scope([](){clean();})` (with `Finally` a variant of `Raii` which executes the lambda at destruction, "similar" to `defer` in *go*).